# Depurar javascript en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, chrome, depuración, visual-studio-2019

tengo una javascript que llama dinámicamente a otro:

```
  // obtiene la url del respectivo reporte
var url = "/ATE/Reportes/" + reporte.replace("/ATE/", '');

// carga filtros 
$("#ReportesDeAtencion #Filtros").load(url);
```

Cuando depuro en Chrome, el javascript llamado, no aparece. Intento entonces depurar en Visual Studio 2019, pero no funciona.

Intenté:

Con Opciones de Internet en Windows para habilitar la depuración con Javascript

Poner a Internet Explorer como navegador por defecto para depurar

Menú Depurar > Asociar al proceso

Pongo el break point, ejecuto la aplicación y el break point cambia, saca la advertencia:

El punto de interrupción no se activará manualmente. No se ha cargado ningún símbolo para este documento

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio ¿Has probado a añadir en el código fuente del fichero que quieres depurar la sentencia`debugger`? Más info: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_debugger.asp

Comment: No... la probé y funciona la depuración. Gracias @ordago